# Does Line support audio & video calls?

Tags: apps

I'm considering switching over to Windows Phone, specifically WP 8.1. However, I was wondering - does [Line](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/line/a18daaa9-9a1c-4064-91dd-794644cd88e7) support voice and video calls? I want to be sure before making the switch.

Comment: Not sure about video, but the Store listing says, quote, "Make Free Voice Call anywhere and everywhere". So I guess it supports voice calls.

Comment: Yes.. It does not support video calling.. But it does support Voice calling

Comment: @VivekParekh, you can probably post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line does support Voice Calls for Windows Phone. But it does not support video calls unlike other OS i.e., Android or iOS.

You can have a look at the screenshot taken from Line's Official website

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As of version 3.9 (released on 19.01.2015), LINE supports video calling on Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1.

From the [Store description](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=a18daaa9-9a1c-4064-91dd-794644cd88e7) (emphasis mine):

> [Update - Ver. 3.9.0]
>   - **Video calling feature supported (OS 8.0, 8.1)**
>   - Addded Italian language support.
>   - Bug fixes and performance improvements

Source: [Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/line-windows-phone-gets-video-calling-latest-update)